# Django app with offline mode: store datas both in remote and local postgresql database?

Tags: django, database, offline

I have a problem quite similar with this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6870347/django-database-synchronization-for-an-offline-usage) but was thinking for an easiest implementation

My Django app is deployed on a remote server with Postgresql database (main central remote database).

1. Users online: data are stored both in the remote database and, if possible, in a local postgresql database (local database hosted on a dedicated laptop)
2. Users offline (when server where app is hosted is down): 'central' user need to be able to use Django web app on the dedicated laptop (with PWA) with the most up-to-date local database
3. When back online, the remote database is synchronized

Django can use multiple databases.
But is my solution possible?

I have read for Django sync and collect-offline apps...

thanks for advices